# Failed to execute goal cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java (generate-sources) project OAS: org.apache.cxf.helpers.JavaUtils.isJava9Compatible()Z

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I have tried changing the compiler and compliance from 1.8 to 11.0 with no change.  I suspect it has to do with the version of Karaf (4.3) and the libraries / bundles / packages associated with that version.

So the question is can I change the version of cxf so the codegen works in the karaf 4.3 environment.  Unfortuneatly I cannot upgrade to a later version of karaf due to existing code base on the current version.

```
C:\Users\MO Tec\git\OracleAtomicService\OracleAtomicService>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< ph.edu.dlsu.esb:OracleAtomicService >-----------------
[INFO] Building Oracle Atomic Service Soap 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] -------------------------------[ bundle ]-------------------------------
Downloading from maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from jboss-public: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (1.8 kB at 810 B/s)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to jboss-public (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public): Transfer failed for https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from jboss-public: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (663 B at 1.3 kB/s)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to jboss-public (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public): Transfer failed for https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from jboss-public: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (749 B at 1.4 kB/s)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to jboss-public (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public): Transfer failed for https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ OracleAtomicService ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\MO Tec\git\OracleAtomicService\OracleAtomicService\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ OracleAtomicService ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.250 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-13T08:23:04+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project OracleAtomicService: org.apache.cxf.helpers.JavaUtils.isJava9Compatible()Z -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Can you run with $ mvn -X to get full debug output?  Also, check your CXF version for JDK and API spec compatability is v3.2.4 a bit dated (over 3yrs old)

Comment: Yes, running mvn clean install -X gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.helpers.JavaUtils.isJava9Compatible()Z
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.CXFAuthenticator.addAuthenticator (CXFAuthenticator.java:55)... will update pom to latest version and see

Comment: Ok changed from 3.2.4 to 3.4.4 (latest) and the error changed to ... Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.4.4:wsdl2java (execution: generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)  I will walk back version by version until I get a positive build.

Comment: at 3.4.2 the error changed to...Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin (org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:3.2.0:bundle:default-bundle:package) org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
 Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute(ManifestPlugin.java:119) at 
 org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:387) at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:378) at 
 org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) at

Comment: The bundle plugin is also quite dated (v3.2.0). I suspect you are running into series of version compatibility across the JDK, Maven, felix-bundle-plugin and cxf-codegen-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem which was resolved by fixing my vpn.
test in a browser window if the wsdl's are available.